Agrupar en Python Dataframe
he buscado pero aun no logro hacerlo, intente con groupby,
tengo el siguiente dataframe




date
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11




0
2024-11-06 19:15:00
849
0
370
0
1743
1801
1790
9167


1
2024-11-06 19:30:00
846
0
368
0
1736
1791
1783
9166


2
2024-11-06 19:45:00
859
0
373
0
1762
1812
1807
9172


.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.


39
2024-11-07 05:00:00
1041
0
445
0
2113
2178
2158
9195


40
2024-11-07 05:15:00
253
0
108
0
2091
2154
2134
9191


41
2024-11-07 05:15:00
809
0
347
0
2064
2128
2110
9188


42
2024-11-07 05:30:00
1001
0
430
0
2042
2104
2085
9187



los valores en la columna date no pueden repetirse, entonces necesito agrupar la fila 40 y 41 en una sola sumando las columnas 4,5,6,7 y promediando 8,9,10,11
muchas gracias por su valiosa ayuda.

para agrupar en pandas es: .groupby(['date'], as_index=False).agg({'4': 'sum','5':'sum'}) o lo que quieras hacer con los campos en este caso sumo los valores para las columnas 4 y 5

Bienvenido, revisar [ask], saludos.

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
